# How can users download files from their own server via another server's path? - PHP

Tags: php, download, stream

i have a problem as described below image,
How do I get the compressed file to the user without server B needing to download all the files?[Describe the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVBcF.png)

Comment: You can redirect them to a URL that downloads from their server.

Comment: One idea is have server A compress the files and store the compressed file somewhere that Server B can access, e.g. cloud storage.

Comment: @Barmar i download multiple files from another server, and return the user a single compressed file, how can i do that without having to download it directly to my server

Comment: That's not possible if the other server doesn't have a way to download a single compressed file.

Comment: streaming zip files (local) on the fly was the keyword I found, and it solved the problem